# Некорректно отображается input на iOS

Tags: html, css, ios

Пытаюсь адаптировать шаблон страницы под мобильные устройства. http://myshop-bal292.myinsales.ru/product/lenta-svetodiodnaya-standart-3528-60-ledm-48-vtm-12v-ip20

В консоли все выглядит в порядке, а по факту на iOS в Chrome и Safari в поле input содержимое сдвигается вниз. Не могу понять из-за чего такая проблема. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

[image: содержимое input сдвигается вниз]

Comment: что именно в консоли всё выглядит в порядке?) отсутствие ошибок? что Вы имели в виду? чтобы решить Вашу проблему предоставьте код всего *некорректного* блока (**html** + **css**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас и в Сафари на macOS также цифра съезжает вниз. Бегло посмотрел, там что-то с высотой блока.

Можно быстро исправить, добавив для **.counter-input** -> `line-height: 2rem;`

```
.counter-input {
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
min-width: 5rem;
border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
background-color: #fff;
color: black;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
height: 2rem;
min-height: 2rem;
width: 5rem;
line-height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!